# "control name" must be convertable to System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: asp.net

I just converted a VB.NET project to C#.  But right now even though the namespace for this inherits is right, all my .aspx pages keep saying "[control name] must be convertable to System.Web.UI.Page"

So in this example when I mouse over Activate I get "Activate must be convertable to System.Web.UI.Page"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Forum.UI.Activate"  Codebehind="Activate.aspx.cs" %>


<asp:Content ID="ctlContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ctlContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Here's the Activate Control:

```
namespace Forum.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Code behind for Skins/SkinName/Activate.ascx.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public class Activate : SkinControl
    {
        #region Private Variables

        private string Key;
        private Int32 UserID;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public Activate()
        {
            base.SkinFileName = "Activate.ascx";
        }

        #endregion

        #region Initialize

        protected override void Initialize(Control ctlSkin)
        {
            // track whos on information
            base.TrackSession(EnumTask.ActivatingAccount);

            // get querystring values
            Key = base.CurrentContext.CurrentRequest.Key;
            UserID = base.CurrentContext.CurrentRequest.UserID;

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (UserID != base.CurrentContext.CurrentUser.UserID)
                {
                    // logout currently logged in user
                    Authentication.Logout();
                    // redirect to this page to refresh controls
                    Common.Globals.Paths.Redirect(Paths.Activate(UserID, Key), false, false);
                }
            }


            bool ActivationSuccess = User.ActivateAccount(UserID, Key,
                                                          base.CurrentContext.CurrentSettings.SharedSettings.
                                                              DefaultUserRoleID);


            if (ActivationSuccess)
            {

                Business.User.UpdatePermissionSet(UserID, 0);


                UserRoles.DeleteUserRole(UserID,
                                         base.CurrentContext.CurrentSettings.SharedSettings.
                                             DefaultAwaitingApprovalRoleID);

                UserRoles.AddUserRole(UserID, base.CurrentContext.CurrentSettings.SharedSettings.DefaultUserRoleID);


                Sessions.Add(EnumSessionObjects.ConfirmationHeader.ToString(), "Confirmation_HeaderActivationComplete");
                Sessions.Add(EnumSessionObjects.ConfirmationMesssage.ToString(), "Confirmation_TextActivationComplete");
            }
            else
            {

                Sessions.Add(EnumSessionObjects.ConfirmationHeader.ToString(), "Confirmation_HeaderActivationError");
                Sessions.Add(EnumSessionObjects.ConfirmationMesssage.ToString(), "Confirmation_TextActivationError");
            }

            Business.User.ClearCache(base.CurrentContext.CurrentUser);


            Common.Globals.Paths.Redirect(Paths.ConfirmationMessage(Sessions.SessionID()), false, false);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

SkinControl.cs inherts a BaseSkinControl.cs and then BaseSkinControl.cs inherits a custom UserControl.cs class and finally UserControl.cs inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl.

This same code worked just fine in VB.NET so I'm not sure why it's complaining.  I have spent countless hours trying to troubleshoot so I'm throwing it up here for hopes at some guesses why this isn't able to resolve.

I don't know if this is enough information but please let me know if not.

Comment: I guess the problem is not with user control hierarchy, but the problem is where you used user-controls in page (Problem is in your page).

Comment: Yea but again this worked fine in VB.NET, same exact solution.

Comment: If you can post some of your page code instead user control code, that may help us to figure out the issue.

Comment: Did you find the problem?  I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct because the code you posted is appropriate for a **UserControl**, not for a **Page**. They aren't the same thing. You can even see in the comments for this Activate class that it was meant to be the codebehind of an ASCX file, not an ASPX page:

> /// Code behind for Skins/SkinName/Activate.ascx.

It's also clear from the inheritance hierarchy you posted that this is for a UserControl.

Check your VB code and make sure that it actually was an ASPX page.